# hibernate.properties (i am using xml) not found

Tags: hibernate

i am new to hibernate.  when i instantiate the session factory, i get the error

INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found

but hibernate.cfg.xml is at the root of src.

here is how i try to instantiate it:

```
SessionFactory hbrntFctry;
    Session rslt = null;
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().buildServiceRegistry();

    try
    { 
        hbrntFctry = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        rslt = hbrntFctry.openSession();
    }
    catch (Throwable ex) 
    { 
        System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex); 
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
    }
```

but then it says:

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: **Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 4 and column 26 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml.** Message: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'hibernate-configuration'.
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.JaxbProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbProcessor.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.JaxbProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbProcessor.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:147)
    at com.foampile.collect.UsgsRetriever.openHibernateSession(UsgsRetriever.java:250)
    at com.foampile.collect.UsgsRetriever.getStateGauges(UsgsRetriever.java:78)
    at com.foampile.base.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:22)
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 26; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'hibernate-configuration'.]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(UnmarshallerImpl.java:419)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:356)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.JaxbProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbProcessor.java:108)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 26; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'hibernate-configuration'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1897)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.validation.ValidatorHandlerImpl.startElement(ValidatorHandlerImpl.java:564)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ValidatingUnmarshaller.startElement(ValidatingUnmarshaller.java:86)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:60)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleStartElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:232)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:354)
    ... 8 more

here is my cfg file:

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/hibernate-configuration">

<session-factory> 

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property> 
    <!-- Assume test is the database name --> 
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/foampile</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property> 
    <!-- List of XML mapping files --> 

    <mapping resource="SiteRecord.hbm.xml"/>

</session-factory>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an error in your hibernate.cfg.xml file. `</hibernate-configuration>` is missing.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
       ...
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```